# Get the exact date and time just 2 days before dates in DB postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table named a125 in my DB postgresql that looks like that :

| objectid | statut | date_debut (timestamp without time zone) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 52138 | validé | 2022-01-18 23:00:00 |
| 52139 | instruction | 2022-01-23 23:00:00 |
| 52140 | instruction | 2022-01-24 23:00:00 |
| 52141 | instruction | 2022-01-26 23:00:00 |
| 52142 | pre-instruction | 2022-01-27 23:00:00 |
| 52143 | validé | 2022-01-30 23:00:00 |

My goal is to get the value (date and time) that equals 2 days before any date in my table in order to compare it with my date_debut column when the current date equals 2 days before any date, I tried to use :

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + integer '2' 
--output : 2022-01-13
```

But the output of that gives me just the current date + 2 days without any time specification;

**My question is :** How can I calculate a value that returns the exact time and date **2 days before any date** stored in my date_debut column?

Comment: you should use time `interval` , see pg documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the specific Timestamps 2 days before the dates in your "date_debut" Column you should use:

```
SELECT date_debut - INTERVAL '2 DAY' FROM a125;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `interval` operator, like so,

```
select date_debut + interval '-2 days' from tbl_a125
```